# TFS check in process gets ora exception 00932

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2012, tfs, fxcop

When I try to check-in (before the actual check-in process starts) I get the following exception : `ORA-00932 - inconsistent datatypes: expected long got char.`

We are running TFS2013 on the server. VS2012 at the client with latest ODAC version. Oracle server version 10.2.

The error is triggered when we turn on the code analysis policy at the server.

Please help us to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is the odac version x86 or x64 ?